# image in clojure

Tags: swing, clojure

I made a frame give a title to it and I added buttons to the frame using clojure. I am not able to guess how to add background image to my frame.

I have a background image stored in the drive, I tried adding the background image in doto panel but it showed series of errors. 
Help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to go a little bit more deep than that. `paintComponent` of JPanel is your entry point. Inside `paintComponent` you can load the image in draw it.
After that, you call `getContentPane().add(new YourJPanel())` of your JFrame.

One a side note. If you are planning to do Swing development in Clojure, did you consider: [Seesaw](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw)?